Expo / React Native - Unable to Load Local Images
I'm building a mobile app using Expo/React Native. As of yesterday all instances of < Image > that use images stored locally using require() have stopped displaying. Sometime I see a black cross on a white background, sometimes nothing. All instances of < Image > that load images from a server are still functioning. I have no idea what could have caused the issue - I've added no new dependencies etc. - but have tried the following to remedy it.

Checking file paths/names
Clearing cache and restarting Metro Bundler
Checking permissions on the relevant files/directories
Assets Configuration in app.json (assetBundlePatterns)
Rebuilding project
Restarting my machine

The odd thing is, other assets from the same "assets" folder as the images are loading fine (fonts, splash screen, etc.). Also, another developer in the team with an identical environment is unable to replicate the issue.
All suggestions welcome!

<Image source={require('../assets/logo.png' + '?' + new Date())} />
can you try it this way?

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/33115 maybe related but not quite the same. On Android native release build, it cannot resolve the local image urls for some reason, and thus crashes.

You do not have a code snippet, however here is an example that should help you.
import {Image} from "react-native";

import {Asset} from "expo-asset"; 

<Image source={Asset.fromModule(require('../assets/logo.png'))} />

Good luck

If you’re dealing with missing images in your Expo app, combining the first and second answers might help you debug the issue. This example utilizes the expo-image and expo-asset modules.
Code Example:
Here’s how you can display an image using the expo-image and expo-asset packages:
import { Image } from "expo-image";
import { Asset } from "expo-asset";

<Image
  style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}
  source={Asset.fromModule(require(`@/assets/images/banner.png`))}
/>;


Important Note:
Make sure to provide the correct path to your images folder inside the require statement.

Configuration for Latest Expo Versions
If you’re using the latest Expo versions, don’t forget to configure the expo-asset plugin in your app.json or app.config.js file. Here’s an example:
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "expo-asset",
        {
          "assets": ["./assets/images"]
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}


import {View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';


<View style={styles.container}>
      <Image
        style={styles.img}
        source={require('./path/to/your/image')}
      />
</View>


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    paddingTop: 50,
  },
  img: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  }
});

I hope you follow that format to load the local images in Expo/React Native. You have to provide width & height dimensions to Image styles to view them properly.
Don't forget to add the file formats in the image path. Like if you're image is logo.png, you have to add the path like  ./logo.png
